# I cannot get Google Sign In integrated

Tags: android, google-signin

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;`enter code here`
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInApi;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;


public class CreateUserAccount extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user_account);


// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        final GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        SignInButton signInBtn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private void signIn() {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                    // ...

                }
            }

            });


        }
    }
```

I followed the steps on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in, but still no luck.

I want to get it to prompt the 'Sign in with google' window, and then return me an Email Address (Or an 'account' object).

Comment: You to check in onActivityResult().

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

go through that link which will fix your issue

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not handled this function:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

See [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java).